# gdi32.dll calls from nvoglv64.dll

Tags: c++, opengl, profiling

I'm trying to profile a 64 bit OpenGL application using the MSVS 2013 profiler (CPU sampling). According to Sysinternals Process Explorer, my application seems to use only 60% of GPU ressources but 100% of a CPU core (since it's only single-threaded for the time being), so the CPU code seems to be the bottleneck. Now I tried to figure out what the hotspots are, in order to optimize/parallelize my code.

However, the profiling results tell that 98% of the time is spent by nvogl64v.dll -- more most notably, 75% within gdi32.dll, 6% in KernelBase.dll.

I have no clue what to do with this information and what optimiziations in my code could help. What conclusion can I draw from that? I'm using freeglut for windowing, the profiler tells negligible 2% is spent in freeglut.dll, thus in my idle and display functions, so I'm not sure if any changes in my update and draw loops would have any effect.

Any hints?

EDIT:
I now figured out how to load according debugging symobols from MS Symbol Servers, now I can go one step deeper into the callstack: Turns out, the portion of gdi32.dll is spent mainly in NtGdiDdDDIEscape (55%) and NtGdiDdDDIGetDeviceState (17%), while KernelBase.dll portion is due to SwitchToThread

Comment: As many people do, you are treating it as a process of measuring various things and puzzling out what's going on. There's a [*more direct way to do it.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)

Comment: @iko79: Do the figures remain the same if you add a `::Sleep(1)` just after `…SwapBuffers`? Unfortunately time spent when waiting for V-Sync is reported quite unfairly; it's reported as consumed CPU time, while actually it can preempted and other threads can use the freed up cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @MikeDunlavey: As far as I understand, the MSVS sampling profiler is doing exactly that.

Comment: @datenwolf: actually, no, this doesn't change much. However, it still seems like waiting for v-sync is the issue, since turning it off resolves the problem. Also, some manual timing measurements showed that by far most of the time is indeed spent in SwapBuffers. Thanks!

Comment: @iko79: Sorry, but it isn't. Profiling has a front end, and a back end. The front end needs to sample the stack, on a wall-clock time interrupt (not CPU-time). The back end needs to allow you, the programmer, to actually see and concentrate on a small number of those samples, not summarize a large number. Speed problems in software are not like in baseball. You're looking for large wastage requiring insight, not small percent differences requiring lots of samples. Example, 30% of time doing something unnecessary: 7 samples expose it, on average.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Okay, thnx. I'm really not an expert in profiling -- I thought, CPU sampling is exactly what you described in your other post. Anyways, recent findings hint towards a fillrate-problem, which kind of confuses me still, since the GPU is only at 60% as I said. Maybe it's best to move over to the OpenGL forum for that since it seems like this will become more of a conversation than a specific question...